# ReactJS fetch server data in a proper way

Tags: reactjs, rendering

So I try to build some React Component on ES6 standars but my code breaks on server data fetching I keep getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`

```
import React from 'react';

class PropertiesList extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){

    super(props);
    this.state = { data:[]}
  }


  loadPropertiesFromServer() {
    $.ajax({
      url: this.props.url,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: (data) => {
        console.log(data);
        this.setState({data: data});
      },
      error: (xhr, status, err) => {
        console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
      }
    });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadPropertiesFromServer();
    setInterval(this.loadPropertiesFromServer.bind(this), this.props.pollInterval);;
  }

  render() {
    var propertyNodes = this.props.data.map((property) => {

    return (<Property>
                  {property.description}
            </Property>)
     });

    return <div className="row">
        <div className="col-lg-12">
          <h1>Available Properties</h1>
          {propertyNodes}
        </div>
    </div>;
  }
}

export default PropertiesList
```

**Entry Point**

```
import React from 'react';
import PropertiesList from './../components/propertylist.jsx';
import Filters from './../components/filter.jsx';
import Properties from './../models/PropertiesModel.js';
    class TransProperties extends React.Component {

      render() {

        return <div className="row">
            <div className="col-lg-9">
                <PropertiesList url="/properties.json"/>
            </div>
            <div className="col-lg-3">
                <Filters/>
            </div>
        </div>;
      }
    }

    export default TransProperties
```

Comment: How are you using this code? You can't "export default" 2 times in the same module

Comment: those are 2 different files

Comment: I edited your question to show it's 2 different files, but it looks incomplete (isn't the 2nd file missing `import react...`?). Is there anything missing from the code?

Comment: The data returned by your server doesn't seem to be an array, therefore it does not have a `map` method. What does the console.log call report?

Comment: Also: you should really clear the interval in `componentWillUmnount`

Comment: On console I do not get any data because of error message. I think I do wrong data binding but I'm not sure about quite new to react

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `render()` method, you try to access `this.props.data` rather than `this.state.data`